# Adding two values in Sass function creates double instance of 'px'

Tags: sass

I have a custom function in Sass that takes an em value, strips the unit and creates a px value:

```
@function stripAndPx($in){
  $stripped: $in / ($in * 0 + 1); //strip unit
  @return #{ (($stripped) * 16) + 'px'}; //convert to px
}
```

I am then attempting to take an em variable:

```
$em-variable: 1em;
```

And add it to a pixel-based variable:

```
$px-variable: 20px;
```

Example:

```
right: $px-variable + (stripAndPx($em-variable));
```

Which creates this output:

```
right: 20px16px;
```

I am expecting both values to be added:

`right: 36px;`

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to add 20px to 1em and get 36px?  While 16px is the standard default font size in most browsers, users can and will change this value, you can never assume that 1em = 16px.

Comment: @cimmanon I have it established as my base px value

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your function is returning a string, not a number.  Sass assumes that you want to concatenate them because that's all it can do with a string and any other type.

```
@function stripAndPx($in){
  $stripped: $in / ($in * 0 + 1); //strip unit
  @return (($stripped) * 16) * 1px; //convert to px
}
```