# SASS doesn't work with "rem" - produces errors when adding two "rem" values

Tags: css, sass

**EDIT: The first addressed thread has the answer to my problem! I'm returning a `String` instead a `Number`from a mixin and so Sass can't handle the value!**

I'm using `Sass 3.2.12 (Media Mark)` for my project (I'm running `Intellij IDEA 12.1` on a `Windows 7 Professional` machine) and I've got some troubles working with **rem** units...

If I want to do something like this:

```
$my-font-size: 2.1875rem;

a {
  font-size: $my-font-size * 1.2;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error design/main.scss (Line 81 of design/_components.scss: Undefined operation: "1.2 times 2.1875rem".)
```

Also, if I try to add two **rem** units, like this:

```
$common-margin: 1.234rem;
.another-class {
  position: absolute;
  top: $common-margin + 0.3rem;
}
```

the preprocesser doesn't give me an error, but the produced output reads as follows:

```
.another-class {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1234rem0.3rem; //<-- what's this!?
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Consider using Stylus (https://github.com/learnboost/stylus) or AbsurdJS (https://github.com/krasimir/absurd)

Comment: Also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197353/adding-two-values-in-sass-function-creates-double-instance-of-px

Comment: @cimmanon thanks a lot - the second thread you posted is the answer to my problem! I, too, returned a `String` from my `@function`s so that Sass just concatenated them instead of adding the values... WHOEVER has the power to change the **this question may already...**, would you mind to reference the second link @cimmanon posted?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define and use a mixin, e.g. [per this article](http://drublic.de/blog/rem-fallback-sass-less/) ([another good one](http://paulwp.com/useful-sass-mixins-for-working-with-rem-units/), oh, [and one more](http://designbyjoel.com/blog/2013-02-28-sass-rems/))

```
  @mixin x-rem ($property, $value) {
      #{$property}: $value * $main-font-size;
      #{$property}: #{$value}rem;
  }
```

Can be called, e.g:

```
@include x-rem(font-size, 1.4);
@include x-rem(padding-left, 2);
```

By creating mixins as appropriate to your site you can get the responsiveness required out of using `rem`, by having whatever your base measure is (as in the above `$main-font-size`) feature in the mixin directly. Dont forget- a rem unit is a relative unit, so you cannot simply specify it directly (as you have with `$my-font-size: 2.1875rem;`).

Comment: actually I'm using a mixin to generate my **rem** units, which is `@function convertPxToRem($px) {@return #{($px/16) + "rem"};};` so that I'm able to write something like this `font-size: convertPxToRem(22);` and so on as this seems to me like it's more readable than several includes where the CSS property is given as a param...?