# Sass variable type handling

Tags: css, sass

How can I get this to work as I expect?

```
// https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/addons/_size.scss
@mixin size($size) {
    $height: nth($size, 1);
    $width: $height;
    @if length($size) > 1 {
        $height: nth($size, 2);
    }
    @if $height == auto or (type-of($height) == number and not unitless($height)) {
        height: $height;
    }
    @if $width == auto or (type-of($width) == number and not unitless($width)) {
        width: $width;
    }
}

$height:10;

.sample {
    @include size(10px $height + px)
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
.sample {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;  
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/2bc77fdb2d5a7d656cf6

Comment: You should replace `$height + px` by `$height * 1px` because you are trying to pass a string(`10px`) as parameter and `size` mixin only accepts unit numbers to set `$height`. By multiplying `$height` by one you are creating the required unit number.

Comment: As a newcomer to sass, I appreciate the answer, I do understand now the "why" .. @cimmanon, the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197353/adding-two-values-in-sass-function-creates-double-instance-of-px) you point to is very specific and for a newbie to sass, like myself, it was difficult to associate and extrapolate my the answer from that question